# Different inner margins with tikzposter

Tags: margins, posters, tikzposter

Is there a way to create different margins on different edges with `tikzposter`?

More precisely, I would like to have a bigger distance from the left edge of the poster to the text than on the right.
There is the `innermargin` option used as follows:

```
\documentclass[25pt,
    a0paper,
    portrait,
    innermargin = 4cm
    ]{tikzposter}
```

But this sets both the margin on the left and on the right to the same value. How can I choose different values?

Thanks

Comment: Minimal code for the users, please

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it can be done directly, but you could hack it by shifting all blocks etc. to the right or left a bit. You could do it by adding the appropriate option to all the blocks, but it can be done globally as well, as in the example below.

```
\documentclass[a2paper, innermargin=4cm]{tikzposter}
\title{foo}
\author{bar}
\makeatletter
\define@key{block}{bodyoffsetx}{\TP@blockbodyoffsetx=2cm}
\define@key{block}{titleoffsetx}{\TP@blocktitleoffsetx=2cm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{foo}{bar}
\column{0.5}
\block{foo}{bar}
\end{columns}
\block{foo}{bar}
\block{}{baz}
\end{document}
```

[image]